# Android App template with Drawer + Toolbar + Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, android-navigation

I'm a veteran Android developer and I'm facing some trouble with the new lollipop infrastructures and I would like to ignite a pretty generic discussion that will lead to a nice powerful and working project template that I think many will benefit from.
(I tought it will be trivial but every approach I take I find plenty of pitfalls)
Imagine I have an app with a navigation drawer (A fragment) that allows me to select one of 5 top level fragments.

3 of the them share a common toolbar behavior, for example something like the Google Calendar app, when the user clicks on the spinner in the the the toolbar slides the content down and shows a date selection above the content.

And yet the 3 fragment need to provide different button in the toolbar ( that should be set as the ActionBar )

The 2 other don't need that common behavior but I'm reminding you that they do need to provide access to the navigation drawer

I want to keep the question short and not pollute the reading minds with the different approaches I tired, I feel this is a pretty common app skeleton.

If you have a suggestion it will probably be best if you try it first.

Note:  I insist on using a toolbar because it's allow higher dev freedom

Comment: I had a similar situation,and I ended using a fragment for the toolbar instead.Will that not provide you greater dev freedom?Instead of a toolbar(action bar)?

Comment: Not really, because I still want to use action buttons and inflate menus and etc.. I hope to get a generic high quality solution and toolbars provide great flexbility

Comment: Yep, would be nice if someone writes a nice tutorial.

Comment: Vote up the question to increase the chance it will happen

Comment: Also, I don't a tutorial is whats needed here, more a customizable template.. If you just take the Android Studio wizard for side drawer you are still left with tonz of work to do to get something like this

Comment: A quick look at Github.com resulted in: https://github.com/danigonlinea/NavDra-material

Comment: Thanks, seems like a good starting point. this Question has an open bounty so please write this comment as answer so you will get the bounty if nothing better comes along :)

Answer (score 1):

@Mldc found a nice 'example' project for how to do this.
Also, it is not difficult to dynamically add action buttons to a Toolbar from fragments.

See the example project on github (https://github.com/danigonlinea/NavDra-material)

[image: Screenshot]

There is a good tutorial on how to use Toolbar [here](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html).

From the link: (You can use a different menu resource file based on which fragment is showing)

> Finally, we call inflateMenu() to inflate a [menu resource file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html). This will display the action item in the Toolbar.
>
> We need to include the Toolbar class’s setOnMenuItemClickListener() method to listen for when the menu’s Action item is selected:
>
> [image: Toolbar Action item click listener]
>
> We attach the listener to our standalone Toolbar. It listens for when a menu item is selected, triggering its onClick() method. Here we include a Toast message to display when the Action item is selected.